# Script to change profile avatars to round avatar

Tags: looking-for-a-script, images

I am trying to customize Vanilla Forum.  I am trying to achieve a similar effect to what Google uses for their profile pictures. (Just like what is on the top-right of Google pages.)

[image: round profile picture]

I have seen this effect before in several discussion pages. I suspect it is a script that crops and adds effects (like shadow), then uploads the avatar into place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this effect with CSS (which is what Google are doing) without changing the image file itself. See: http://bavotasan.com/2011/circular-images-with-css3/

This will work in most browsers, but not IE8 or older. See: http://caniuse.com/border-radius

Comment: I can't upvote your answer but I can say thank you.